# How do you add your react build to existing asp.net website?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, build

I've been trying to implement webchat made with React to an existing website created with ASP.NET razor pages.
When I click on minimized button it should expand it but instead it disappears from DOM and in console I get "TypeError: n.render is not a function".
It works fine on my local html file, but when I put this on server it breaks on first interaction.

Maybe this is not enough:
`<link href="static/css/main.0602d322.css" rel="stylesheet"> <div id="root"></div> <script defer="defer" src="static/js/main.20fceca6.js"></script>`

I tried to implement it in various ways but non seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the root element to the html as well?

`<div id="root"></div>`

The react components will be rendered there.

Comment: Yes, I did. Everything is in html.